# Best practise for counting data in java

Tags: java, data-processing

Lets say there is a pool of data taken a CSV file where we have a key value pairs, but keys are not unique. The requirement is to sift through each and every line and convert the CSV data into something useful. I'll make an example using a game log with format:

```
player, pointChange, timestamp
```

What I would like to do (which seems like a common operation) is to create a summary - how many points has over time. My idea was to create an inner class that represents a single entry:

```
private class GameFrame{
    private String player;
    private int points;
    private ArrayList<String> timeline = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<int> pointHistory = new ArrayList<int>();
    GameFrame(String player, int points, String time){
       this.player = player;
       this.points = points;
       this.time.add(time);
    }
   public String getName(){return this.player;}
   public void increment(int change){ 
      this.pointHistory.add(this.points);
      this.points += change;} //will work with negatives to decrement points as well
   public void timeProgress(String time){this.time.add(time);}
}
```

**The actual challenge:**
The original data is of unknown size and is read line by line. Is there a good practice/recommended method to process such data. I was thinking about making a list of all GameFrame objects and nesting a second loop, something like this:

*pseudocode*:

```
for(everything in the input list){
    load up line data;
    for(everything in gameFrame list){
        compare names;
        if names match - update with data
        return;}
    got out of inner loop so it's a new player.
    create entry for new player and add it to gameFrame list
}
```

Is it a good approach or there is a better way of doing it (perhaps to sort the data first or by using a library I don't know about)?

UPDATE:
I will try to do this using a hashmap instead of ListArray as suggested by Luke

Comment: Kinda depends what figures you actually want here, how much this could change into the future, etc. Could just run through it and use a standard old HashMap to store KeyValue<String, Integer> pairs. Or, my favourite: parse it all, chuck it in a database. Databases are fantastic at working with sets of data!

Comment: I think I could actually embed a lightweight database into the thing - I was working with HSQLdb not that long ago and it works nicely, but I still would need to *somehow* get to know names of all players before I can filter by the names.

Comment: Any DB. Why would you need to know the players? Just have a `frames` table with `player`, `pointChange` and `timestamp`. Then insert rows. Then you can `select distinct player from frames;` to get all players, `select player, sum(pointChange) from frames group by player;` to get points, etc.

Comment: But this is entertaining the idea of bringing in a database for one job. Have you considered the super simple HashMap solution, also? What sort of processing will be necessary, how often, how many records?

Comment: The records would probably not exceed a 1000. I will look at the hashmap. I still get the data in the form of csv file, but it's not a subject to a change  (unless a new file is provided) - it's just to draw statistics of the game.

To select a distinct player I need to know his name as per Select * FROM frame where player="name";, don't I?

Comment: Yes, true. But you would need to know the player's name with any other method, surely? Be it a key in a dictionary or a field on a database record.

Comment: Not at first - I would just loop through everything to BUILD the list of players from the file and sort the data in a sense (create individual records for each player). I think I might be able to pull this off with a hashmap - just create an extra hashmap whenever a new player is found in the file and if a key already exist just update it's value (Which would be my container object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Heavy solution: Database**

More appropriate if you're going to have lots of records, you want to do the parsing/inserting in one session once, and then do processing later/multiple times, and if you're going to be appending data constantly. Databases make it really easy to work with sets of data.

Create a table named `frames`, with fields `player` (varchar), `point_change` (int) and `timestamp` (datetime), or similar. In the parsing step, simply insert the rows. Then you can `select distinct player from frames;` to get all players. Or `select player, sum(pointChange) from frames group by player;` to get points for a particular player. Or include the timestamp in a where clause to get points over a particular window of time.

**Light solution: HashMap**

More appropriate if you're going to do this one time. Or if there are so few records that it can be run many times trivially. It avoids the whole 'setting up a database' step.

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public void insert(String player, int scoreChange) {
    Integer value = map.get(player);
    if (value == null)
        value = 0;
    map.put(player, value + scoreChange)
}

public void getScore(String player) {
    Integer value = map.get(player);
    if (value == null)
        value = 0;
    return value;
}
```